# Turtlebot communication over Xbee

Tags: turtlebot, ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ROS and I am in need of some guidance of where to start with this project. I am currently running ROS fuerte and Ubuntu 12.04.

I am currently working with a Turtlebot 1 and would like to alter the communication between the workstation and the Turtlebot laptop to communicate over radio instead of ethernet as it does now. I plan to use an Xbee series 1 modem attached to the workstation and turtlebot laptop. (more generally I need my ROS nodes to communicate using a radio signal rather than wifi or ethernet)

My question is where to start within ROS packages to change the communication? Also I have come across rosserial and rosserial-xbee and was wondering if anyone knew if these might be used to achieve what I am looking to do?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50897/turtlebot-communication-over-xbee/) by [JillTurtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/3786/jillturtle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2012-12-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I was able to figure out how to do what I wanted and this is the current solution I have so far:

workstation --> xbee-pro-pkg_modem   and turtle_laptop --> xbee-pro-pkg_modem

I simple have the modem connected to the USB ports of each computer and then I use:

> > slattach /dev/ttyUSB0

open a new terminal:

> > ifconfig sl0 [ip_addr of yourself] pointopoint [ip_addr of other computer] netmask 255.255.255.0

** make sure you run the above commands on each computer and then you should be able to ping eachother and ssh from one computer to the other. with this setup running roscore and the other turtlebot software should work.

hopefully someone else finds this useful!

---

Originally posted by [JillTurtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/3786/jillturtle/) with karma: 51 on 2013-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) on 2013-01-11**:
Why did you decide to not use Wifi? I do not think the XBee throughput is high enough to transfer any image data between the workstation and the turtlebot and I do not really see the upside of using XBee either

**Comment by [JillTurtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/3786/jillturtle/) on 2013-01-14**:
We are using XBee because there are restrictions on WiFi availability (aka WiFi 802.11 is not an option).... I didn't think that XBee would be a realistic option for the image data either, but I was unsure so thank you very much for verifying my suspicion!

**Comment by [halamesp](https://answers.ros.org/users/38049/halamesp/) on 2018-10-15**:
I have the same problems with you. Could you please give me more details about the procedure.And what about the Ip Address ? Xbee should not have IP address and only have PanID.  Thanks a lot !

**Comment by [tilak](https://answers.ros.org/users/39439/tilak/) on 2019-01-12**:
@halamesp Have you figured out about xbee having Ip address ?